# Wordpress like shortcodes in asp.net pages?

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, shortcode

I'm an experienced asp.net developer who has begun developing in php, specifically in wordpress.  I'm impressed with the ease of use of shortcodes in wordpress and how simple they are to develop in php.  I know you can get similar functionality from user controls in asp.net but they are not as intuitive and simple to use for the end user as shortcodes are.  Is there any open source (or commercial) development  of a shortcode parsing/rendering engine for asp.net? If not, what would be my best approach in developing this?  Thanks in advance for any information or suggestions.

Comment: I guess the similar `asp.net mvc` introduced the helper methods

Comment: As above i think this is what you get with MVC and the Razor view engine... http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: [Using Wordpress style short codes in Asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41591608/using-wordpress-style-short-codes-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ASP.NET Routing, Request Handlers (ashx or web.config-based), WebMethods, or Razor pages. Only the last requires MVC or ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor-formatted cshtml pages).